# Monitor a variety of things

Tags: php, node.js, monitoring

In an application of mine, I want to monitor a variety of services at once, and at best, in a single way.

The app uses NodeJS as a web server, as well as WebPack watcher. There is also a PHP part of the app that uses Workerman and othe rmodules - and I would like to collet stats from all of them.

For a smaller view, let's imagine I have two scripts: `app.js` and `backend.php`. The JS file is a small webserver that serves pages with React and stuff, and the PHP script serves as a way to access the database via AJAX and do other, better-done-in-PHP things.

What I want to do now is to collect stats. Like when someone connects to the nodejs server, I want to raise a counter named "requests" by one, and when something specific in the database is accessed though PHP, I want to also push a counter.

What systems are out there that will allow me to collect statistics across languages? My stack of software is: Redis, MySQL, PHP, NodeJS.

Comment: If you're trying to persistently collect data from multiple processes, then  you probably just want a multi-user database so each process can just update the one database anytime it has some data to record.  You can likewise then use the database for generating reports from the database (searching, querying, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Axibase Time-Series Database](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/) Community Edition. It's free. It has integrated rule-engine for alerting and graphs for visualization. There is a PHP client and [statsd storage driver](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/backend.md)

Disclosure: I work for the Axibase.

Comment: Looking into it. For it having a free version, it looks very powerful and interesting. Any known client libraries for it? Or may I should ask, are PHP and NodeJS clients available?

Comment: There are 5 supported client libraries at this time: Java, R, PHP, Python and Ruby. Some of the them can both write and read data, while others such as R are only for reading data. Am I correct that you basically need to increment counters in PHP and nodejs pages and functions?

Comment: Yes. I want to keep track of the performance at various points. So it only is about writing, not reading. Reading will be required when displaying the collected data.

Comment: If you need visualization, the built-in widgets should cover it: http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/visualization/widgets/

Comment: @IngwiePhoenix: A [Node library](https://github.com/axibase/atsd-api-nodejs) was released a month after this answer was published.

Answer (score 0):

Two options - use database (MySQL?) or use monitoring/analytics tool.

First option will give you flexibility but would require some dev work from you.

Second option would require deploying monitoring tool and implementing events. For this you can use web analytics tool (good because you can use it to monitor backend processes, client side events and product related events if it is needed, and all at the same place) like Google Analytics or http://piwik.org/... or you can use something like Graphite http://graphite.wikidot.com/ (graphite is quite weird comparing to other analytics tools, but it serves the purpose), also for it you should use libs to push stats to it, like statsd: https://github.com/etsy/statsd

Any of mentioned will allow you to nicely monitor stuff...

In case of web analytics with javascript API, you should build wrapper in node with route for PHP to ping and send event name... VOILA

Comment: I have found StatsD and Graphite and, as you mentioned, they are quite the odds. But they seem to be one of the few self-hosting services for monitoring. The other systems I saw were SaaS ones which I would have to pay for. But I am just a one-man dev-army with no income (: ... Do you know osme alternatives to Graphite+Statsd that I can deploy on my own server?

Comment: Piwik is self hosted, but it is web analytics... I do not know any other self hosted monitoring tool

Answer (score 0):

You can always implement some custom made tracking and save data to existing data storages. But proper instrumentation is not so easy.

I would not recommend to use MySql as a storage. MySql performance for inserts is not so good, so that could slow down your application and introduce a lot of overheads.

Redis is fast but not good structured for time events and series.

There are some special time series databases that are tailored to work with logs, metrics and timeseries: https://influxdb.com, http://graphite.wikidot.com/, http://elastic.co, ...

But, actually, there are some tools that would fit your needs out-of-the-box. Moreover you can pick some of SAAS services for logs and metrics.
There are services that provide both good libs for nodejs/php and hosted stack of proper tools to store data and to analyze it.
While you have less then 10k requests per day that should be cheap / free.

For opensource instrumentation lib and hosted influxdb+grafana or ELK stack take a look http://devmetrics.io/logslib and logs/metrics guide: http://www.devmetrics.io/blog/post/logs-vs-metrics-best-practices

For proprietary tools take a look at http://datadoghq.com, http://newrelic.com, http://boundary.com